# Cant open new window with button in javaFXML

Tags: java, javafx

[UI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GECOD.png)

Hello for school i had to make a project where students can check in and check out for lectures and that professors can see who is coming to the lecture and who is not coming to the lecture.

for this i have made a UI where students can check in and check out for different lectures.

i made a button at the tableview named "toon afwezigen" to open a new FXML window, but this button doesn't work. can someone help me to fix this issue

the code below is my code that i tried.

i tried to open it with:

```
    public MainDataModel(String tijd1, String lokaal1, String les1, String leraar1) {
        this.tijd = new SimpleStringProperty(tijd1);
        this.lokaal = new SimpleStringProperty(lokaal1);
        this.les = new SimpleStringProperty(les1);
        this.leraar = new SimpleStringProperty(leraar1);
        this.button = new Button("Toon afwezigen");
        this.button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("AfwezigenScherm.fxml"));
                    Parent root = loader.load();
                    Stage newStage = new Stage();
                    newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
                    newStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    newStage.showAndWait();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        });
```

but it still doesnt work can someone help me please.

the error that i get:

```
Error resolving onAction='#handleButton', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
```

Comment: [mcve] please (mind the __M__ - nobody wants to wade through tons of unrelated code :)

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly (assuming you build your ui completely with fxml: required are controller, application, fxml and complete stacktrace)

Answer (score 1):

In your FXML file the function `handleButton` is called. You must declare this function.

You probably want something like that in your controller:

```java
    @FXML
    private Button newStageButton;

    @FXML
    public void handleButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("newStage.fxml"));
            Stage newStage = new Stage();
            newStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            newStage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

And the button is declared in your FXML file:

```
<Button fx:id="newStageButton" onAction="#handleButton" text="NewStage" />
```